# Angular doesn't recognize a function defined within a controller

Tags: angularjs

I wrote a litlle program in angular which contains a function that check if a string is in a given string array.
Here is my angular code **inside** my controller :

```
$scope.currencies = ["EUR", "USD", "GBP"];
$scope.languagesValues = ["en", "nl"];

function searchStringInArray(str, strArray) {
    for (var j=0; j<strArray.length; j++) {
        if (strArray[j] === str) return j;
    }
    return -1;
}

$scope.saveGeneralParams = function(){

if (searchStringInArray($scope.paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue, $scope.languagesValues) === -1){
   $scope.paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue = 'en';
}

if (searchStringInArray.inArray($scope.paramsGEN.cur.paramUserValue, $scope.currencies)=== -1){
   $scope.paramsGEN.cur.paramUserValue = 'EUR';
}
//other things.....
```

In my html code, I have this code :

```
<select id="language" name="language" ng-model="paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue">
  <option ng-repeat="language in languages" value="{{language.value}}">
    {{language.name | translate}}
  </option>
</select>

<select id="currency" name="currency" ng-model="paramsGEN.cur.paramUserValue">                              
<option ng-repeat="currency in currencies" value ="{{currency}}">
  {{currency}}
</option>
</select>
```

But this code doesn't work and angular display me that : "Error: a.searchStringInArray is not a function".

How can I fix that?

Comment: When is this function getting called? Also, in the second if block, you have written searchStringInArray.inArray -> this doesn't seem to be defined?

Answer (score 0):

Array has an 'includes' method you should use. See the [MSDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Try:

```
if ($scope.languagesValues.includes($scope.paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue)) {
  $scope.paramsGEN.lan.paramUserValue = 'en';
}
```

That should do it for you.

Comment: As I understand, includes method checks if a string is included in ANOTHER string no? Whant I want to do is to check if a string is included in a string array. I'm not sure it's the same thing...

Comment: I've edited this to say Array, that was my mistake, thought I had typed Array!